# JMeter SPARQL Queries

Tags: jmeter, sparql, response-time

I am using the JMeter tool to evaluate the performance testing of several SPARQL queries. I use the "`Sampler`" and "`Http request`" section of Jmeter (like [this image](http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/http-request-raw-single-parameter.png) ) to write the SPARQL queries. However it does not work as JMeter does not give me the actual response time of the queries. The more complex query has the same response time or even less. Maybe I have to use other options of JMeter.

Does anybody have an experience on this?

Comment: "Does anybody have an experience on this?" is not code and does not need to be marked up as code.  See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more help.

Comment: I thought you are answering the question...

Comment: Could you clarify more on the problem?

Comment: It seems "http request" feature of JMeter only calculates the response time of the URL and not the whole query results. JMeter has another option called "JDBC connection" that can calculates the response time of SQL queries which is useless here, as I am using SPARQL endpoints. Maybe I have to ask another question: what is the best tool for calculating the response time of SPARQL queries for concurrent users!?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [SPARQL Query Benchmarker](https://sourceforge.net/p/sparql-query-bm/wiki/Introduction/) tool (*disclaimer* - I am the primary author on that tool) which is specifically designed for this purpose

It distinguishes between response time as being the time when the first result is received from the remote system and runtime as the time taken to receive all results.  The [Benchmarking Methodology](http://sourceforge.net/p/sparql-query-bm/wiki/BenchmarkingMethodology/) page describes more about the difference between these metrics and the various other metrics which the tool calculates.

Since many systems execute queries and generate results in a streaming fashion for complex queries you will typically see noticeable differences between these two figures.  Of course systems vary so not all systems will display quite the same variations between the two metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could run finally with the following command: "java -cp sparql-query-bm-cli.jar net.sf.sparql.benchmarking.commands.BenchmarkCommand -q http://mySPARQL_Endpoint/sparql -m mix.txt -r 250 -w 10 -c results.csv" The explanation was fair enoug